# Why is stored date a month different than what's created / logged?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this Firebase Function incrementing some stats (It has been cut down a bit, but nothing that should impact my issue):

```
exports.processRecordEventStat = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const n = new Date();
  const d = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth());

  console.log(d);

  //Add to aggregate stats
  let aggStatDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('businesses').doc(businessid).collection('aggregatestats').doc(`${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth() + 1}`).get();
  if (aggStatDoc.exists)
    return aggStatDoc.ref.update({ [stat]: firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), date: d });
  else
    return aggStatDoc.ref.set({ [stat]: 1, date: d });
});
```

When this function runs I see this log in the console and the date looks correct (current date accurate to the month):

[image]

But when viewed or retrieved from Firestore my date becomes:
[image]

**Why is the date a month off after being stored in the document?**

Comment: You happened to choose the last day of the month.  One date is displayed with respect to your local timezone (which is still Feb 28); the other with respect to GMT (which wrapped over to March 1).  Hence the "month" difference :)  Exactly the same date/time - simply two different "display" representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every platform has its own way of displaying date/time objects. While luckily the Firebase console and the Functions logger agree on the date value here, there's nothing that forces them to agree on how to display dates.

If you look carefully you'll see that the two timestamps are actually the same, and the only differences are in the timezone and display format. Midnight of March 1 in UTC was actually 6 pm on February 28 in PDT.

The Cloud Functions log seems to use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and UTC timezone (which I usually prefer), but the Firestore console uses the default JavaScript format (which is also very common) and displays them in pacific time (which is quite common for Google services).

Comment: When I do `new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()).getTime()` on my machine I get a result of 1614578400000. However logging `d.getTime()` in my firebase function results in 1614556800000. Shouldn't the number of milliseconds since the Epoch be the same?

Comment: @Tristan `getTime()` will return the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 in UTC. But because you set your date based on local time (getYear, getMonth) you are setting a different timestamp, to adjust such a date to UTC, you'd have to subtract your timezone offset (which is in minutes) from the result, like `let d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()), msUTC = d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;`. It's often simpler to use [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp).

Comment: @samthecodingman Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I read the docs of `.getTime()` on MDN which states it's always calculated using UTC. I just assumed that was the case elsewhere.

Comment: @Tristan Let's say I used `new Date(2021, 2)`. On a cloud function, this gives `2021-03-01 00:00 UTC` / `1614556800000`. On my system, it would give `2021-03-01 00:00 AEST`, which is actually `2021-02-28 13:00 UTC` / `1614517200000`.